# The network connection was lost on macOS

Tags: swift, url, networking, urlsession

I have a swift code shared between macOS and iOS. My MacBook and iPhone are both connected to the same wifi, but the code works only from iOS device. I'm on macOS Sonoma & iOS 17, but don't believe it's the root of the issue. The error in Xcode is:

```
Connection 1: received failure notification
Connection 1: failed to connect 1:57, reason 18 446 744 073 709 551 615
Connection 1: encountered error(1:57)
Task <D8541ECD-3BFA-4225-902F-DE2DB77DC000>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: 18 446 744 073 709 550 611 [1:57])
Task <D8541ECD-3BFA-4225-902F-DE2DB77DC000>.<1> finished with error [18 446 744 073 709 550 611] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003bf5740 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, dns, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<private>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<private>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

If I do the same network call via cURL it works perfectly, so there is no problem on server side, it must be something in the Xcode settings specific for mac..
The relevant network code is here:

```swift
func login(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
    let loginURLString = "\(baseURL)/Core/Default/Login"
    guard let loginURL = URL(string: loginURLString) else {
        completion(.failure(KayakoError.invalidURL))
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: loginURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    configureRequestHeaders(&request)
    
    let bodyData = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)".data(using: .utf8)
    request.httpBody = bodyData
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            completion(.failure(KayakoError.invalidResponse))
            return
        }
        
        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
            if let data = data {
                let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
                let loginResponseParser = LoginResponseParser()
                parser.delegate = loginResponseParser
                
                if parser.parse() {
                    let sessionID = loginResponseParser.sessionID
                    completion(.success(sessionID ?? ""))
                } else {
                    completion(.failure(KayakoError.invalidData))
                }
            } else {
                completion(.failure(KayakoError.invalidData))
            }
        } else {
            completion(.failure(KayakoError.loginFailed))
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: On your macOS target, have you enabled the outbound (client) network [capability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-capabilities-to-your-app)? Apps cannot make network request without explicitly enabling this capability.

Comment: Yes, network client is enabled.